# File not found exception during post request

Tags: javascript, post

I developed the following source code in order to send a json string to a server :

```
httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
}
httpRequest.send("parameters="+JSON.stringify(myJSONObject));
```

With `JSON.stringify(myJSONObject)` containing my json data.
The send method throws to me the following exception and I understand very well :

```
[Exception... "File error: Not found"  
nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  
location: "JS frame :: chrome://___file.js :: method :: line 150"  data: no]
```

Comment: I would check the URL you're POSTing to. Also, try disabling all your extensions or try in a different browser (thereby confirming that one or more browser extensions are the culprit).

Comment: I found my problem, I just had to add "http://" to my url.